# Send meeting reminders on screen from google calendar

Tags: google-chrome, macbook-pro, google-calendar

My previous company used MS Outlook and anytime I had a meeting, a reminder would pop up in a corner of my screen and stay there until I saw it/cleared it.

My new company uses Google calendar.  When I have a meeting now, the reminder only appears on the tab of Chrome that has calendar open.  I've missed a couple meetings already because I forgot I had them and the reminder appears in a tab I wasn't monitoring.

Is there a way to make Google calendar pop up a reminder somewhere on my screen and stay there so I can notice it easier or am I out of luck since it's a web application and only running in Chrome/a browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/settings
2. Click or scroll down to the **Event settings** section.
3. Set the **Notification settings** option to **Desktop notifications**
   [image]

You may be prompted by your browser to enable notifications for the Google Calendar website. You can also change this setting manually if you are not prompted:

1. In Chrome, click the padlock icon next to the URL while on the Google Calendar site, and click Settings from the menu.

[image]

2. Set **Notifications** to **Allow**

[image]